# Oracle Dynamic Query for all tables

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have two queries,
first one to get the table name and avg_row_len

```
select Table_name, AVG_ROW_LEN  from all_tables
where Table_name = 'COMPU_ERROR_FACT';
```

and then i need to pass the avg_row_len to

```
SELECT  COUNT(1) as "Number of Count", 
        ROUND(COUNT(1) * avg_row_len/1024/1024) AS "Size in MB" , 
        TO_CHAR(CREATE_DATE, 'YYYY') AS YEAR,
        'CREATE_DATE' AS DATTT
FROM COMPU_ERROR_FACT --table name
GROUP BY  TO_CHAR(CREATE_DATE, 'YYYY')
order by 3;
```

I have more than 2k tables and is there a way to get the details of all tables at one-time execution.

Please suggest,

Comment: Do you need this to be a single query (which your question implies)?  You could do something with XMLQuery but that tends to be pretty esoteric.  Or can you use some PL/SQL that, say, writes data to a table that you later query (which your tags imply)?

Comment: Well, this will fail one way or another unless each of those 2K tables contains the CREATE_DATE column. Do they?

Comment: yes, all of them having the Create_date

Comment: Do you like to get the size of the tables? If yes, then view `ALL_SEGMENTS` might be better.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if you need just a query or a PLSQL block.

So, if you need a query, you may build it with the following PLSQL code. Run it and run huge sql from the output. Don't forget to remove trailing "union all"

```
begin
  for t in (select * from all_tables) loop
    dbms_output.put_line('select count(1) "number of count", ROUND(COUNT(1) * avg_row_len/1024/1024) "Size in MB", TO_CHAR(CREATE_DATE, ''YYYY'') AS YEAR, ''CREATE_DATE'' AS DATTT
                        FROM t.table_name 
                       GROUP BY  TO_CHAR(CREATE_DATE, ''YYYY'')
                      order by 3');
     dbms_output.put_line('union all');
  end loop;
end;
```

In case if PLSQL is acceptable you may use this

```
declare
  cnt number;
  avg_len number;
  create_year varchar2(4);
  dattt varchar(10); -- in youe example it will get constatly populated with 'CREATE_DATE', check if you need it at all
begin
  for t in (select * from all_tables) loop
    execute immediate 'select count(1) "number of count", ROUND(COUNT(1) *     avg_row_len/1024/1024) "Size in MB", TO_CHAR(CREATE_DATE, ''YYYY'') AS YEAR,     ''CREATE_DATE'' AS DATTT
                        FROM ' ||t.owner || '.' || t.table_name ||
                       ' GROUP BY  TO_CHAR(CREATE_DATE, ''YYYY'')
                      order by 3'
    into cnt, avg_len, create_year, dattt;                          
    -- do something with data you've just selected
  end loop;
end;
```

And please note that all_tables has names of all tables you have access to. So there will be system tables and tables from another schemas. this is why I added "t.owner".

Perhaps you need user_tables view which has names of objects your user has created only. Check if  using of "user_tables" system view will do better job here.

FYI: table size in MB may be obtained from dba_segments table:

```
select bytes / 1024 / 1024 from dba_segments where segment_name = 'TABLE_NAME'
```

Comment: How to run the huge sql from the output?

Comment: @author4 copy it to the clipboard and paste it to where you run SQLs

Comment: ... and remove the trailing `UNION ALL`;)